# How to insert data to a table using transient model(wizard) in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have a model named Vehicle and i have created a wizard od_add_new_vehicle.
In the xml view of wizard i have created an action.
How do i link the Vehicle model with the wizard so that i can save data permanantly

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    _name = 'transport.vehicle'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    description = fields.Text()
    reg_date = fields.Date()
    department = fields.Char()
    available = fields.Boolean()


class od_add_new_vehicle(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'od.add.new.vehicle'
    _description = 'Add new vehicle'
    name = fields.Char('vehicle name')
    description = fields.Text('Description')
    reg_date = fields.Date('Reg date')
    department = fields.Char('Department')
    available = fields.Boolean('Available')

    def _default_veh(self):
        return self.env['transport.vehicle'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids'))

    v_id = fields.Many2one('transport.vehicle', string="Vehicle ref", required=True, default=_default_veh)

    @api.multi
    def od_add_book(self):
        self.v_id.name = self.name
        self.v_id.description = self.description
        self.v_id.reg_date = self.reg_date
        self.v_id.department = self.department
        self.v_id.available = self.available
        self.v_id.member_id = self.member_id
        return {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is simple way to update/insert data from Wizard.

- Add button on form view footer
- Button type will be *object* to call python function in .py side
- Use *active_ids* to update record-set.

For example:

```
<footer>
    <button name="insert_data" string="Insert/Update data" type="object"
        class="oe_highlight"/>
    or
    <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel" />
</footer>
```

.py side function

```
@api.multi
def insert_data(self):

    for record in self.env['target.table.name'].browse(self._context.get('active_ids', [])):

        #here you can access target table fields using *record* variable

        record.field_name = wizard.field_name

    return True
```

Comment: Odedra thanks for your reply. I have tried with the code i have mentioned in my question, it gives me the following error "ValueError: Expected singleton". My requirement is to insert new row

Comment: Check your code. Somewhere *Many2one* field gets *ids more then one* So ensure that it will take only 1 record-set id.